# Same report, different databases

Tags: business-objects, multiple-databases

I created reports on Web Intelligence accessing an Oracle database. But now, other people want the same reports. Each one of them has a different database (but all are Oracle) with the same structure but with his own data.

What do I have to do to make the same reports available for all? The reports are the same, but the connection or universe changes depending on the user that is running it.

I don't want to make a copy of them to each person, because any change on one report has to be available for everybody.

Regards,
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

If this product sits on a server, you might be able to exclude the database login and password, so the user has to enter in a separate login and password for the database they have to log into. Perhaps this is something your DBA sets up for each database user to have read-only access to certain tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are built on top a "classic" UNV universe, this can be done at the universe level by defining connection restrictions. If you are using a new BI4 UNX universe, you will need to create Data Security Profile Connections. Both of these mechanisms allow you to map alternate database connections for different users within the same universe (and therefore share the same documents based on that universe).

This functionality is fairly well described in the Universe Designer documentation (for UNV) and the Information Design Tool User Guide (for BI4).